# Javascript String Splitting with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split an input string using regular expressions and the split() method as part of a codewars problem. However, as of yet I've been unable to create a regular expression that will correctly split my input string. The input string follows the below format:

```
x+y=z
```

Where x, y and z can be any integer (positive or negative), that also contain question marks. For example:

```
12?+-756?=1??
-3445--8?756=?32
1+1=?
```

etc

The task is to solve for the '?'.

So far I've split the string into two strings; the left and right hand side of the equals sign. Now, I'm trying to further split the left hand side. However, as the input string can contain a minus operator and or negative numbers, this is causing an issue in my program.

So far I've used:

```
x = /[+*-]/;
```

Which works in simple plus, minus or subract scenarios with positive integers.

If anybody could help with this I would be very grateful.
Thanks.

Here is a link to the codewars kata:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/546d15cebed2e10334000ed9/train/javascript

Comment: Can you specify more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
([+-]?[\d?]+)[+-]([+-]?[\d?]+)=([+-]?[\d?]+)
```

This part `([+-]?[\d?]+)` specifies an optional positive or negative sign, then a mix of digits and question marks, then `[+-]` is either plus or minus, then another number, then `=` another number. Each number is captured in a group so you'd be able to access it after executing the regex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I inserted this code into my program and managed to get it working. I've been reading a few online tutorials about regular expressions and didn't really understand, but I think the solution that you provided has helped me understand more. Really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh great! No problem. I use this site https://regexr.com/ sometimes to test out regular expressions. If you haven't been there it might be good to help you get more familiar with them

Comment: @sbrass, I tested your regex on `-1?2?3*45?=5?088` - didn't match.

Comment: Ohh sorry! It only checks for addition and subtraction. `([+-]?[\d?]+)[+-*/]([+-]?[\d?]+)=([+-]?[\d?]+)` That one should add multiplication and division